# Android debugging without USB connection [device is not connectable]

Tags: android, debugging

I am android app developer and in my work my boss wants to develop on EVOLVEO ANDROID BOX Q5 4K (http://www.evolveo.eu/en/android-box-q5-4k) and this device is not connectable through USB to the computer, so I am not able to debugg through USB.

I was looking for some solutions and I found debugging through wifi. This seems legit, but problem is that I have to run adb shell command (adb tcpip 5555) to enable wifi debugging on device, but I cannot do that because I cannot connect device through USB.

Is there a way to open tcpip port 5555 for debugging without connecting to computer through USB?

Comment: Debugging can be done using TCP on android,
 check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Visit https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_tv it can be done hopefully

Answer (score 0):

For some devices we can't debug our app directly like normal, for those we need configure device to connect to our local machine. We need add VendorID & ProductID in androidsdk. These VendorID and ProductID are specific for device company and model. Do check android official doc for configuring device VendorID and PoductID.

Hope this useful..

@Rajesh